# jQuery non-responsive click event

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to build a basic slider in jQuery.  I have 5 primary  sections that display on a page, and when you hover over their container div, then arrows pop up on the first and last elements.

My next step is to write code that will store the div (either left or right depending on click side) in an array, and remove it from the DOM.  However, I'm having trouble tying into the click event.

Here's my css:

```
.left_arrow_background {
 height: 175px;
width: 65px;
/* background:url(../images/left-arrow.png) no-repeat; */
background:#ccc;
opacity: .9;
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 2;
}

.right_arrow_background {
height: 175px;
width: 65px;
/* background:url(../images/right-arrow.png) no-repeat;*/
background:#ccc;
z-index: 2;
opacity: .9;
position: relative;
left:890px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.boomers_scroller {
height:275px;
padding-left:1px;
display:block;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #CCC;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.all-boomers {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 225px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
width: 175px;
}
```

And the HTML that's output:

```
<div class="all-boomers">
<a href="/boomers/profile/id/2"><img src="/images/users/medium_thumbs/4fa44866c3561.jpg" alt=""/></a>
      <p class="boomers_name">PC Guy</p>
      <p class="activity_name">IT Guy PC Repair</p>
    </div>
<!-- three more identical section here -->
<div class="all-boomers">
<a href="/boomers/profile/id/6"><img src="/images/users/medium_thumbs/4fa62dff64c44.jpg" alt=""/></a>
      <p class="boomers_name">Cruella Deville</p>
      <p class="activity_name">Dalmation Dog-Sitter</p>
    </div>
```

Even when removing `z-index` from the style sheet, I can't seem to record a click event.  Here's my js file so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var boomers = $('.all-boomers');
  var boomersLength = boomers.length;
  var boomersContainer = {};
  $(".all-boomers:eq(4)").attr('id','right-boomer');
  $(".all-boomers:eq(0)").removeClass("all-boomers").addClass("one-fifth first").attr('id','left-boomer');
  var image_left = '<div class="left_arrow_background"></div>';
  var image_right = '<div class="right_arrow_background"></div>';

  $(".boomers_scroller").hover(  
    function(){
        $(image_left).insertBefore('#left-boomer');
        $(image_right).insertAfter('#right-boomer');
    },
    function(){
        $('.left_arrow_background').remove();
        $('.right_arrow_background').remove();
    });

  $("div.left_arrow_background").click(function(){
    var left_boomer = $('#left-boomer').children();
    // store left_boomer in boomerscontainer, then remove it from dom
    console.log('clicked!');

  });
 });
```

It's not just click events... I've tried other mouse events as well, and nothing triggers the console test message, or if I put code inside the .click function, it won't trigger the code.

Edit: added a 4th (relevant css style)

Comment: I'm wondering if changing the `.click()` function to `.live()` might work?  if the js interpreter reads the entire script before inserting DOM elements, then the element the listener is attached to wouldn't exist when it's parsed.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, (thought I had tested it)... will try it's replacement `.on()` in a few hours when I'm back on my dev machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed! The hover event is still occuring when I'm clicking, so nesting the click event inside the hover event clears up the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var boomers = $('.all-boomers');
var boomersLength = boomers.length;
var boomersContainer = {};
$(".all-boomers:eq(4)").attr('id','right-boomer');
$(".all-boomers:eq(0)").removeClass("all-boomers").addClass("one-fifth first").attr('id','left-boomer');
var image_left = '<div class="left_arrow_background"></div>';
var image_right = '<div class="right_arrow_background"></div>';
$(".boomers_scroller").hover(       function(){ 
     $(image_left).insertBefore('#left-boomer');
     $(image_right).insertAfter('#right-boomer');
     $("div.left_arrow_background").click(function(){
           var left_boomer = $('#left-boomer').children();
          // store left_boomer in boomerscontainer, then remove it from dom
          console.log('clicked!');    });
 }, 
function(){ 
    $('.left_arrow_background').remove();
     $('.right_arrow_background').remove();
 });
 });
```

Comment: why the neg votes? I joined this site to participate on both sides of the fence, and posting an answer to this will undoubtedly help someone in the future. And no reason given for the vote down either...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the ready() function(or to copy it before pasting it here :)
Add one more }); to the bottom of this code.
Here it is isolated:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3rDz/

Comment: Didn't forget... There's just the right side click function under the left befor I close it... Didn't bother to oaste the redundant code

Comment: np (end it with '...' next time so we know) Isolate the click event and the left html and see if it works.

Comment: I can't isolate exactly, as every piece of code above is necesarry to even get the opportunity to click on the sections I'm concerned about. I did howver put a `$('*').click(function(){ // code that changed titl tag to click target});` and the click target was represented in the way I would expect.... I just can't get it to trigger any code inside the specific `.click()` funcitons I've written.